# Doesn't recognize Label on the Userform

Tags: excel, vba

For several months macros has been working OK. Now nothing was changed in a code and it can't recognize label on the userform:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
Path = Sheets("Settings").Cells(2, 1)
With PrintCh
.Top = center
.Height = 120
If Len(Path) * 10 <= 260 Then .Width = 265 Else .Width = Len(Path) * 7 + 5
End With
With Label1
.Caption = Path  **'this string an ERROR: "Object variable or With block variable not set"**
.Width = Len(Path) * 7'**this string an ERROR: "Object variable or With block variable not set"**
End With  
End Sub
```

Nothing helps - restarted, changed the label name, recreated new label, created new userform -nothing helps. What to do?

Comment: Most likely the form doesn't have a label with the name `label1`. a) Use `Option Explicit`, compiler will complain if label1 is missing. b) Write Me.Label1 - intellisense will show you the controls that are available on the form.

Comment: What do you mean by "changed the label name"? Please, click on the label **you think it should be `Label`**, being in VBE (Visual Basic for Applications Editor) and press `F4`. You will see the (real) name of that respective label and it must be used instead of `Label`. As stated before, it is good to cultivate the habit to fully qualify the object and also benefit of Intellisense suggestions. In the code context, please use `Me.PrintCh` and `Me.Label1`. When you start writing `Me.Lab`, intellisense will show all matching control names. If the label you need is not shown, it does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

After the investigation was noticed problem wasn't shown on the other computers, so was solved after reinstall of MS Office. Maybe, some libraries got unavailable for some reason.
Many thanks to Billy Gates for the lost half of the day.
And thanks @ FaneDuru for the advice - the note about usimg `Me.Lab` was new for me.